# Powershell Module Manifest "ScriptsToProcess"

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell module I am writing and one thing I was curious of that is a bit unclear is the ScriptsToProcess Key. Can or should I use this to verify certain things like OS Type, Bit Type, or the presence or lack of certain environment variables to throw warnings if some of my functions may rely on some of the requirements above?

Comment: Looks like I was able to use this Key to throw a warning but I haven't a clue if this is a bad practice etc. Any information anyone else can dig up outside this article that I was falling back on would be appreciated. [MS PS Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878297(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ScriptsToProcess` to execute script in the caller's session state (create variables, etc) or to use Write-Warning to notify the user the prereqs haven't been met.  However, even if you throw an error, the module is still loaded. So if your intent is to prevent loading of the module I would put the warnings/throws in the startup script of your `ModuleToProcess`/`RootModule`.  The module will show up in the Get-Module list but there shouldn't be any exported commands.  Also if you want to check bitness, use the module manifest `ProcessorArchitecture` key.